# How to test Vue component height or width?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs

I am going to make test on the element size of Vue component with Jest.
But what I got is **0** in console. I tried several attributes like `clientHeight`, `offsetHeight` etc.
why the value is **0** even if element is loaded, which I can see the text content of that element.

```
....
describe('Mount Cmp', () => {
     const localVue = createLocalVue()

     const wrapper = mount(mycomp, {
        localVue,    
     })

     const titleHeight = wrapper.vm.$el.querySelector('.title').offsetHeight

     console.log(titleHeight)
.....
})
```

Answer (score 1):

> Your test can only detect inline styles when running in `jsdom`. [Reference](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/#detecting-styles).

Consider this HTML template:
`<li style="padding-top: 10px" class="message">{{ message }}</li>`.
You can get **INLINED** `padding-top` like this:

```
it("Message component has style padding-top: 10", () => {
  expect(wrapper.find(".message").attributes().style).toBe("padding-top: 10px;");
});
```

Comment: so is it impossible to get the height of element defined in class, the component has no inline style since I used css framework

Comment: No, there is definitely no way :(. Seems like [cypress](https://www.cypress.io) should fit your needs.